# Set table cell height to fraction of total window height in HTML

Tags: html

I currently have a table, with cells containing text. They are all at a current height of 100, but I want them to scale with browser size, so the page always fits on screen without the user scrolling.

```
        <td width="200" height="100">
            <h1 align="center"> <font color="AEDBFB">Blue</font></h1>
        </td>
```

What can I put in place of the "100" to make it say 10% of the screens height?

Comment: What environment is this for? 72% of your code is deprecated.

Comment: Ima be honest AuxTaco, this is day 1 of HTML. I'm a highschool student, and I have a scheduling app for my school that looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/N9ajoWT Im trying to make a web version.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion could be to use a combination of the CSS function `calc` and the CSS unit `vh` for viewport height:

```
<style>

  td {
    height: calc(100vh / 10);
  }

</style>
```

Comment: No need for `calc`. 100vh / 10 is 10vh.